# $L_1 ∩ L_2$ is not regular while $L_1$ is regular and $L_2$ is not regular language

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Could you give me an example of languages $L_1$ (regular) and $L_2$ (not regular) where $L_1 \cap L_2$ is not regular?

Comment: What did you try to find one yourself?

Comment: Seriously, what have you tried? What properties would L1 have so it _doesn’t_ turn a non-regular language into a regular one? There is an obvious L1 that will work with any non-regular language.

Answer (score 2):

Take $L_2$ to be any nonregular language, say $\{0^n 1^n: n \ge 1\}$ and let $L_1 = (0+1)^*$ be the set of all strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$.  Then $L_2$ is a subset of $L_1$, and their intersection is $L_2$, which is nonregular.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\Sigma = \{a\}$. A straighforward example is $L_1= a^*$, $L_2 = \{a^p| \text{p is prime}\}$. So, $L_2 \cap L_1 = L_2$ and it is not regular.